# Generating sequential invoice numbers without a database

Tags: php

I am creating an invoice in PHP and for the invoice number I'd like to generate a sequential number.

I'm using gettimeofday() in order to generate the invoice number now but this gives me a non sequential number which looks something like this: 46023913

```
<?php 
$new_invoice = gettimeofday(); 
$new_invoice = $new_invoice[sec]; 
$new_invoice = $new_invoice - 1509000000;
echo $new_invoice;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a text file 'counter.txt' with a number in it (1509000000)
Read the file with file_get_contents(counter.txt) then update the file

I haven't worked in php for a while but it goes something like

as per KIKO: lock the file

```
<?php

$num = file_get_contents('counter.txt');

echo $num;
$handle = fopen('counter.txt','w+');

if (flock($handle,LOCK_EX)){

  $num++;
  fwrite($handle,$num);
  fclose($handle);
  // release lock
  flock($handle,LOCK_UN);
} else {
  echo "Error locking file!";
}

$num = file_get_contents('counter.txt');

echo $num;
```

something like that.

Comment: This is an obvious solution, and it will work 99.999% of the time. Except when it doesn't. Some user might read the content of `counter.txt` just before you can write the new invoice number, and voila you have two invoices with the same number. You need to **lock the file**. I will upvote your answer if you add that.

Comment: Hi Richard,Thanks for your answer but this only works once for me. If counter.txt is read only I get 101 (I'm using 100 instead of 1509000000) every time. If I make it writable it works once but the number 100 gets deleted so the next time I get nothing. Any idea why the contents of counter.txt are getting deleted?

Comment: @KarimBoroumand The code is currently a bit of a mess, and doesn't work. `fopen()` should return a file handle, but it doesn't, and `$handle` is used as string.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks for your response. I just want to make sure I understand your code. If it works the idea is to take whatever number is in counter.txt add 1 to it and also write this number to the counter.txt file replacing the old number. Is this correct?

Comment: @KarimBoroumand - yes that is correct.  I have updated my code for effectiveness and simplicity.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I had to remove my upvote because your code doesn't handle file locking properly. The biggest problem is that you read the `counter.txt` file while it is not locked. This means it could be overwritten before you write your own updated number to it. Both reading and writing should be performed while the lock is in place.

Comment: I can't get the latter code to work. It doesn't write properly to the text file.

Comment: @KarimBoroumand - are you using PHP 7 or something earlier? PHP7 requires (for some reason) $num = $num + 1; instead of $num++;  Does that help?

Comment: I've tried it both ways. The problem I'm having is when the text file is overwritten with the new value it is skipping spaces.

Comment: from php.net (fopen): 'w+' Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.  so I'm not sure why you're getting that in your file.

Comment: @richardwhitney but you are using "r+" in your second example. If I change it to "w+" it doesn't work at all. I'm using PHP version: 7.2.7 and mysql - 5.1.73

Comment: I think you're confusing the different posts - I have only 1 - the one you marked as accepted answer and I used w+   I don't know your environment but my code works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Richardwhitney has now included the file lock, but it's not done very well. If a lock already exists his code will produce an error. That's not pratical. The code below will wait up to 10 seconds for the file to be unlocked.

```
// open the file
$handle = fopen("counter.txt","r+");
if ($handle) {
    // place an exclusive lock on the file, wait for a maximum of 10 seconds
    $tenths = 0;
    while (!flock($handle, LOCK_EX)) {
        $tenths++;
        if ($tenths == 100) die('Could not get a file lock.');
        usleep(100000);
    }
    // get old invoice number
    $oldInvoiceNo = fgets($handle);
    // create a new sequential invoice number
    $newInvoiceNo = $oldInvoiceNo++;
    // write the new invoice number to the file
    ftruncate($handle, 0);
    fwrite($handle, $newInvoiceNo);
    // unlock the file
    flock($handle, LOCK_UN);
    // close the file
    fclose($handle);
}
else die('Could not open file for reading and writing.');
```

When locking files, always try to do this for the shortest time possible.

It is best to isolate this code from the rest of your code, for instance in a function.

```
function getNewInvoiceNo($pathToCounter)
{
    // open the file
    $handle = fopen($pathToCounter, "r+");
    if ($handle) {
        // place an exclusive lock on the file, wait for a maximum of 10 seconds
        $tenths = 0;
        while (!flock($handle, LOCK_EX)) {
            $tenths++;
            if ($tenths == 100) die('Could not get a file lock.');
            usleep(100000);
        }
        // create a new sequential invoice number
        $newInvoiceNo = fgets($handle) + 1;
        // write the new invoice number to the file
        ftruncate($handle, 0);
        fwrite($handle, $newInvoiceNo);
        // unlock the file
        flock($handle, LOCK_UN);
        // close the file
        fclose($handle);
    }
    else die('Could not open file for reading and writing.');
}
```

Comment: Had some time to set it up and test it - it should work now - I updated my answer.

Comment: Adding that $num++ does not seem to work in php7.x use $num = $num + 1; instead

Comment: @richardwhitney thanks for updating your code. But when writing to the counter.txt file spaces are being added which makes everything not work the second time.
'100      (Starting with 100 in counter.txt)
   101   (Second time 3 spaces over)
      1    (Third time 6 spaces over and only writes 1 instead of 102)'
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: If you're using 'w' or 'w+' in fopen() it should not do that

Comment: @richardwhitney I got it to work with the first code you gave me. I think the reason it wasn't working was that echo $num; was written twice. Works like a charm and it's much simpler than the other code you gave me. Anyway thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @KarimBoroumand You're writing your comments underneath the wrong answer. Worse: The solution you now seem to be using is imperfect. It will work most of the time, but not always.

Comment: The echo $num was just for testing.  Sorry about that!